# RavenDb GenerateDocumentKey

Tags: ravendb

I need to generate Id for child object of my document. What is the current syntax for generating document key?

`session.Advanced.Conventions.GenerateDocumentKey(document)` is not there anymore. I've found `_documentSession.Advanced.DocumentStore.Conventions.GenerateDocumentKey` method but its' signature is weird: I am okay with default key generation algorithm I just want to pass an object and receive an Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default implementation of GenerateDocumentKey is to get the "dynamic tag name" for the class, and append a slash. For example, class `Foo` would turn into `Foos/` which then goes through the [HiLoKeyGenerator](https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Client.Lightweight/Document/HiLoKeyGenerator.cs) so that ids can be assigned on the client-side without having to consult the server each time.

If you *really* want this behavior, you could try to use the HiLoKeyGenerator on your own, but have you considered something simpler? I don't know what your model is, but if the child thing is fully owned by the containing document (which it should be, to be in the same document) have you have several much easier options:

1. Just use the index within the collection
2. Keep a `int NextChildThingId` property on the document and increment that every time you add a ChildThing
3. Just use a `Guid`, although those are no fun to read, type, look at, compare, or speak to someone over the phone.